# Does this stylistic guideline have a name?

Tags: grammar, phrases, writing-style

The principle would be something like:  Avoid a long modifying clause that creates distance between your subject and verb

For example, according to this guideline, the sentence

> One of his uncles who had made millions of dollars in the oil industry
> in the sixties by inventing a new kind of pump left John a giant
> inheritance.

should be rewritten as follows:

> One of his uncles had made millions of dollars in the oil industry in
> the sixties by inventing a new kind of pump.  This man left John a
> giant inheritance.

Does this principle or guideline have a name? Bonus points for references to any books or websites that discuss it.

### EDIT - A related link

[This article](http://www.llas.ac.uk/materialsbank/mb063/eap/05/vs70402.htm) discusses using noun phrases instead of clauses as a way to improve writing.  While more focused than the principle above (and still without a name), I thought it was a good guideline, and it's the closest thing I've found so far.

Comment: It's the essence of Orwell's Sixth: _Break any ... rule sooner than say anything outright barbarous._ The original Sixth is _Break any of these [first 5] rules sooner than say anything outright barbarous._ You'll find them at http://grammar.about.com/od/writersonwriting/a/OrwellRules.htm .

Comment: I don't see how this applies, even if you meant it as a joke.

Comment: "Barbarous" can mean "bad style" in this case. You seem to think that creating "distance between your subject and verb" is bad style in the single sentence version, so you made one sentence into two and added words probably better omitted (rule 3). That sentence should probably be rewritten in an entirely different way: _John inherited a fortune from an uncle who had made millions (in the sixties[Superfluous, it seems to me]) by inventing an oil pump_. Barbarous is as barbarous does. Both your examples are stylistically less than optimal. The answer @Edwin gave is good: no joke.

Comment: @BillFranke, Neither of the sentences was being offered up as an example of stellar writing.  I just needed a quick example so that I could ask my question.  I agree your rewrite is better, but it does not illustrate the principle I am asking about.  My question is not about how to rewrite a particular sentence in the best way.  I just want to know if the principle has a name.  If you don't like my example sentences, feel free to edit with better ones that illustrate the principle.

Comment: I think Edwin's comment points to a good guideline (and presumably the reason why Orwell broke his fourth "rule" more often than the average writer, in that essay as a whole), but isn't appropriate here. It would be appropriate if Jonah decided after the re-write to go back to the first sentence.

Comment: @BillFranke it's reasonable as an example, as long as one views the second as even marginally better than the first. As a "rule", reducing distance between subject and verb is ridiculous, but it certainly can be useful to look for such distances between subject and verb (or within split verb forms, and some other cases) to find cases where you are at risk of losing the reader.

Comment: @JonHanna, I'll be the first to admit the example is a bit strained.  This principle comes up naturally when I edit, but unfortunately I didn't have one of these "in the wild" examples on hand when I thought to ask the question, so I quickly made one up.

Comment: Yes, it's easy to create a sentence that breaks it to a ridiculous extent by adding in more and more clauses, but that wouldn't be the only fault with such sentences. (Incidentally, I was joking when I said that I believed Orwell broke his fourth rule to keep to the sixth. Truly, I believe he did so because his fourth rule is outright nonsense, and Orwell's instincts as a writer were too great to let him follow it, even in the course of expounding it. Strunk & White similarly break it a great many times when making the same point, because White was a better writer than writing theorist).

Comment: @JonHanna, Yeah as a "rule" his fourth is nonsense, but I do think it has value as a guideline.

Comment: It seems to me that my revision illustrates the principle in both clauses: "John inherited" & "an uncle who had made millions". We can follow Orwell's 6th rule more closely by saying "John was left a huge inheritance by an uncle who had made a fortune...". This also solves the problem that your first sentence illustrates. Sometimes recasting the sentence is required.

Comment: @Jon: I think the first sentence is typical of how many writers try to stuff their sentences with as much info as possible without thinking about how it reads, so I'm sympathetic on that point. There are many ways to revise the sentence to bring the subject & verb closer: one is by making a complex sentence; another is use two sentences.

Comment: @BillFranke yes, the sentences that I change on second draft that had such a large distance on first are normally because I was guilty of exactly that. I take such distance as a warning sign, but neither as a sin in itself, nor as the only thing that needs fixed in such a sentence, if anything does.

Comment: @Jonah: I think realistically if we're going to suppose there might actually *be* a specialised term relevant to this issue, it would more likely be something meaning *the words/distance between subject and verb*. (Or perhaps if we can temporarily just neologise that as the [incertum](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incertum), something meaning *excessive incertum!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I think that might unfairly slander "incertum," which after all [can be quite lovely](http://www.proprofs.com/flashcards/upload/q4033556.jpg).  Since we are unnaturally stretching the distance between subject and verb, I would propose such sentences be described as "procrustean" :)

Comment: @Jonah: I cannot tell a lie. I'd never heard of "incertum" until just then. But I happened to notice it on a Google link when I searched for **grammar terminology subject verb "words in between"**. Naturally, I thought I'd hit pay-dirt, but obviously my hopes were dashed. It's not in OED, btw (because it's just half of the Latin *Opus incertum*, I guess).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not a rule, it's a guideline. Your first sentence is after all grammatically correct. If we used commas to make the part from *who* to *pump* a parenthetical clause as thus:

> One of his uncles, who had made millions of dollars in the oil industry in the sixties by inventing a new kind of pump, left John a giant inheritance.

Then it isn't even a difficult sentence to parse.

The reason for the guideline is threefold:

1. With a greater distance between subject and verb there comes a greater chance of introducing an error or ambiguity by e.g. having a noun in the piece between the subject and verb that could be mistaken for the subject. (So while it's not a rule, following it makes us less likely to break a rule by mistake).
2. It **tends** to make for snappier and more easily understood sentences.
3. It tends to make for shorter sentences, which in turn **tends** to make for snappier and more easily understood sentences. (Favouring short sentences is a guideline in itself).

It's very important to stress the difference between a guideline and a rule. Knowing the rules let's us write English that is correct. Knowing the guidelines can help us write English that is not only correct, but good.

At the same time, breaking the guidelines is often the best approach to a given sentence, paragraph, etc. that results in stronger writing than if it was followed. Breaking the rules is in the "don't try this at home" territory; there are times that it can be done, but they are rarer, require more skill to carry off, and even the greats can sometimes produce questionable results.

Also, the way we might debate rules and guidelines differs too. If someone were to say (as some have done) that there is a rule against splitting an infinitive, then it can be debunked by showing that it is commonly done and produces a clearly understandable expression. If someone were to say (as others have done) that while there is no such rule, there is a guideline to avoid it, then to argue against one must show that the product of ignoring it is as good, or better, than of following it—and that will be subjective at the best of times.

In terms of your question, this distinction is relevant. The rules of grammar are studied not just by those of us who wish to follow them well, but by those of us who want to understand how language works; to know the explanation for why "the cars is parked outside" is not something we would say (that being an example of *agreement*, specifically *agreement in grammatical number* because *cars* is plural and *is* is singular).

The guidelines are more given to disagreements of personal opinion (can you imagine if Philip Roth were forced to follow the guideline of avoiding long sentences or Ernest Hemmingway forced to abstain from sentence fragments?), often vague in definition (how large a distance between subject and verb do we need before we consider your guideline broken?), often contradictory (the guideline against long sentences conflicts with that of using longer sentences in the middle of a paragraph than at the beginning or end), and harder to detect (how to judge a conscious effort to keep subject near verb from simply not having much to add between them?).

These features in themselves make them less likely to have name, and less likely again to have names that are universal. I **personally** think of "proximity" when I'm wondering if I have stretched words too far from their companions, but that would certainly not be a good name since "proximity principle" is term for a grammatical rule.*

The stylistic principles we do have names for tend not to be those that help writing be clear and understandable, as those which are used for specific effects. Often these go against the first set of principles, as *diacope*, *anaphora* and *epistrophe* along with many others go against the general guideline of avoiding repetition.

Between it not being a firm rule and it being vague, I think the odds of finding a fully agreed on name are slim. No doubt some people have names for things, as we're all given to naming things and those of us who worry about distance between subject and verb particularly so, but I'd be more surprised if they are widely accepted and used by others.

*Not an uncontroversial one. The proximity principle has us write "more than one bystander was hurt" rather than "more than one bystander were hurt", because we have *was/were* agree with *bystander* which is singular, rather than the whole phrase *more than one bystander* which is plural. However, some would disagree with this one, and some who would agree would disagree in other cases that some people use it. The proximity principle is perhaps more useful in speaking descriptively of what people do write, than prescriptively about what you think people should write.

Comment: Jon, thanks for taking the time to write such a long and thoughtful response.  In my defense, I made a point of saying "rule OR principle" (intending principle as a synonym for guideline as you are using it) to avoid getting sidetracked by the issue of exactly how hard (or loose) this guideline is.  I really was just curious if it has a name.  I did edit the OP to remove the word "rule" so that others wouldn't be distracted by this point either.

Comment: Indeed, I noticed that edit part way through. My main point though is not just to point out that it's a guideline rather than a rule, but that as a guideline, the greater degree of subjectivity, vagueness, openness to debate and lack of universal applicability is precisely a reason why they are less likely to have a name that is widely used. All that said, I think this guideline **is** a good one; I wouldn't say all sentences should be re-written to follow it, but I would say that sentences that break it are sentences where **considering** a rewrite would be profitable.

Comment: Agreed on all points.  And I wasn't terribly optimistic of getting an answer for the reasons you mention, but I figured there was some chance someone has named this principle.  If no one else comes in with a definitive answer, I'll accept yours.

Comment: Yes, I do hope I'm wrong. It's always good to learn a new word, or a new sense for a known word.

Comment: There's also a syntactic source for this guideline; I'm working on it. But this is good stylistic advice for English. +1.